# <select> returning empty if the value isn't edited

Tags: javascript, html, django

So, I am working on an ticket system using Html, Css, JavaScript and Django, and I needed an field that changed depending on another field, after some searching I found a good JavaScript implementation to my case and it worked perfectly on the ticket creation part, but as I was doing the ticket editing part I got stuck with a problem, if there is no changes on the <select> field it simply gets an blank value instead of the value it was previously holding, changing the value works just fine but not changing it doesn't, I can't think of a way of preventing this yet and would like to ask if anyone has dealt with an similar problem that could help me.

verticket.html(form part)

```html
<form name="form-ticket" id="formTicket" method="POST" action="{% url 'eticket' ticket.pk %}">
    <div class="col-4 mt-4 m-auto">
        {% if msg %}
            <div class="alert {{class}}">
                {{msg}}
            </div>
        {% endif %}

        {% csrf_token %}
      
        <input class="form-control mt-4" type="text" name="numctt" id="numctt" value="{{ticket.numctt}}" placeholder="{{ticket.numctt}}">
        <input class="form-control mt-4" type="text" name="nomctt" id="nomctt" value="{{ticket.nomctt}}" placeholder="{{ticket.nomctt}}">
        <select required name="areaserv" id="areaserv">
            <option disabled selected hidden>{{ticket.areaserv}}</option>
          </select>
          <select required class="followup" name="tiposerv" id="tiposerv">
            <option disabled selected hidden >{{ticket.tiposerv}}</option>
          </select>
        <input class="form-control mt-4" type="text" name="tickettext" id="tickettext" value="{{ticket.tickettext}}" placeholder="{{ticket.tickettext}}">
        {% block usuario %}
        {% if not request.user.is_staff and ticket.ticketstat == 'Vermelho' %}
        <input class="btn btn-primary mt-4" type="submit" value="Atualizar">
        {% endif %}
        {% endblock %}  
</form>
```

verticket.html(script part)

```js
const first = document.getElementsByName('areaserv')[0];
const second = document.getElementsByName('tiposerv')[0];
const initial = second.innerHTML;

const optionMap = {
  Informática: ['Visita Técnica'],
  CFTV: ['Instalação', 'Reparo'],
  Alarmes: ['Instalação', 'Reparo'],
  Interfones: ['Instalação', 'Reparo'],
  Telefonia: ['Instalação', 'Reparo'],
};

function addOption(selectElement, text) {
  let option = document.createElement('option');
  option.value = text;
  option.textContent = text;
  selectElement.append(option);
}

Object.keys(optionMap).forEach(text => addOption(first, text));

first.addEventListener('change', evt => {
  second.innerHTML = initial;
  optionMap[evt.target.value].forEach(text => addOption(second, text));
});
```

views.py

```python
def verticket(request, pk):  
    ticket = Userdb.objects.get(pk = pk)
    context = {'ticket': ticket}
    return render(request,'dashboard/verticket.html', context)
```

I've tried multiple solutions to "fill" the field but the didn't work, changing the selected to selected="true" or selected="{{ticket.areaserv}}" even selected="selected", tried giving it an value and it didn't work too

If any more information is required please feel free to ask.

Comment: You didn't define `values="...` in your `<option>`s?

Comment: I tried this
 `<select required name="areaserv" id="areaserv">
            <option disabled selected hidden value="{{ticket.areaserv}}">{{ticket.areaserv}}</option>
          </select>
          <select required class="followup" name="tiposerv" id="tiposerv">
            <option disabled selected hidden value="{{ticket.tiposerv}}">{{ticket.tiposerv}}</option>
          </select>` and it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Just found what was wrong, apparently I needed to remove the `disabled` tag on the `<opition>` and then put the `value` tag on it with the values, the end result was this:

```
<select required name="areaserv" id="areaserv">
  <option selected hidden value="{{ticket.areaserv}}">{{ticket.areaserv}}</option>
</select>
<select required class="followup" name="tiposerv" id="tiposerv">
  <option selected hidden value="{{ticket.tiposerv}}">{{ticket.tiposerv}}</option>
</select>
```